# sound recorder with silverlight or flash

Tags: silverlight

can i record the sound with microphone, with help of flash or silverlight??

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Both technologies allow you to do this, though the methods for doing so differ.  I can't give details on a Flash implementation of it, but Tim Heuer's video gives a good walkthrough of how can access both the webcam and the microphone in Silverlight.

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-videos/access-web-camera-microphone/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not certain about flash but with silverlight I know that you can't.

Probably never will be able to do so.  Think about browsing to a silverlight site that activates your microphone and records conversation in your office.  Sounds like a bad idea to me!

Comment: This feature was recently added in Silverlight 4.  It does require user consent, but it's quite possible.